# Export all subscription RBAC with focusing on Azure AD groups and resolving users assigned

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

What would be best way to export all subscriptions with their RBAC but focusing on AAD groups and resolving user membership? I seems to be lost in if statement.

```
Get-AzSubscription | 

foreach-object {

    Write-Verbose -Message "Changing to Subscription $($_.Name)" -Verbose

    Set-AzContext -TenantId $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.Id -Force
    $Name     = $_.Name
    $TenantId = $_.TenantId
    $SubId    = $_.SubscriptionId  

        Get-AzRoleAssignment -IncludeClassicAdministrators | Select-Object RoleDefinitionName,DisplayName,SignInName,ObjectType,Scope,
    @{name="TenantId";expression = {$TenantId}},@{name="SubscriptionName";expression = {$Name}},@{name="SubscriptionId";expression = {$SubId}
    } 

        if(Get-AzRoleAssignment.ObjectType -eq "Group") 
        {
        Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId.Id  | Select-Object DisplayName,SignInName,ObjectType,Scope | foreach-object { Get-AzADUser | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,ObjectType,Id
            }
        }
        else { continue }
    } 

-OutVariable ra
$ra | Export-Csv -Path .\Export-SubAzRolesGroups-$Name.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest / quickest way would probably be to use powershell with the az module, write a little script to, get all subscriptions that account has access to (hopefully using some kind of tenant wide reading permission user), then get all role assignments for each subscription, and do whatever you need to do get the groups, and get members for each group. the write it all out to files.

the powershell commands you want to look into is:
get-azsubscription
get-azroleassignment
get-azadgroup
get-azaduser

other options include, you can use azure resource manager Rest API, or some other azurerm library to write an application that does the same.

hopefully that gets you started.

**UPDATE**

```
Get-AzSubscription | 
foreach-object {
    Write-Verbose -Message "Changing to Subscription $($_.Name)" -Verbose

    Set-AzContext -TenantId $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.Id -Force
    $Name     = $_.Name
    $TenantId = $_.TenantId
    $SubId    = $_.SubscriptionId  

    Get-AzRoleAssignment -IncludeClassicAdministrators | Select-Object RoleDefinitionName,DisplayName,SignInName,ObjectId,ObjectType,Scope,
    @{name="TenantId";expression = {$TenantId}},@{name="SubscriptionName";expression = {$Name}},@{name="SubscriptionId";expression = {$SubId}} | 
    foreach-object{ if($_.ObjectType -eq "Group") 
        {
            $_ | ft
            $group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $_.ObjectId
            $group | Select-Object DisplayName,SignInName,ObjectType,Scope | ft
            $group | Get-azadgroupmember | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,ObjectType,Id | ft
        }
        else { $_ | ft}
    }
} -OutVariable ra
$ra | out-file .\Export-SubAzRolesGroups-$Name.csv
```

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to do with the get-azroleasignment long statement then the if statement after that? i'm not sure i understand what you are trying to do there, are you trying to print all the rbac role assignments for all scopes? eg for each app and everything? or are you just trying to get the rbac for the subscription level?  then when you run into an rbac entry with a group in it, to further break out the group into its users?

Comment: I edited your script a bit, its not perfect, but should get you a bit closer to what you want.

Comment: I was trying to export all RBAC per subscription and expand group membership to have full visibility rather than to run separate report for each AAD group.

Comment: I was just thinking if this is quicker(if possible) with running Azure Graph with KQL? Anyone tried

Comment: i don't believe you can get role assignments from the azure resource graph explorer using kql, so that may be an issue with that approach

Comment: I tried to run it with -out-file but the formatting seems to be crazy. Once I put Export-csv i got only one subscription.

Comment: because there are different tables / formats in there, because the role assignment table is different from the subs table which is different from the groups  and users tables, so export-csv will get confused as it is expecting only 1 format. i'm not sure how you plan on formatting the data so that they are all uniform that's why i just out-file

Comment: RoleDefinitionName,DisplayName(Group or user),SignInName,Group->User(ObjectType),Scope,TenantId,SubscriptionName,SubscriptionId
Each iteration should occurs for users as original script but groups should be expanded like with nested groups, im not sure if that make sense?

Comment: I totally understand what you mean, but in terms of a csv, i dont know how that would even be possible, because the csv format consists of 1 set of header columns, then data that matches that format. eg, subscriptionid, subscription name. then in the data rows it should show say 123123-123123, subscription 1. the next row in a csv wouldn't be able to show say a role definition, as the format would be different. there would need to be different fields that's why it would have to be some kind of out-file formatted in the way you want.